# DOM node in the $ method?

Tags: jquery

how can you put a DOM node in the $ method?

```
$(this.loader).fadeIn(1000);
```

have also tried

```
this.loader.fadeIn(1000);
```

EDIT:

DOM.div() returns a div element object

```
function Loader(){
    this.loader = null;
    this.threads = 0;

    this.cnstr = function(){
        if(this.threads == 0){
            this.loader = DOM.div(document.body);
            with(this.loader){
                className = 'loader';
                innerHTML = 'loader';
                style.opacity = 0;
                style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=0)';
            }
            $(this.loader).fadeIn(1000);

            elm_position_center(this.loader);
        }           
        this.threads++;
    };

    this.dstr = function(){
        this.threads--;

        if(this.threads <= 0){
            this.threads = 0;

            if(this.loader){
                DOM.rmv(this.loader);
            }
        }
    };
}
var Loader = new Loader();
```

if I reverse the animation like this it works

```
this.loader = DOM.div(document.body);
            with(this.loader){
                className = 'loader';
                innerHTML = 'loader';
                style.opacity = 1;
                style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=100)';
            }
            $(this.loader).fadeOut(1000);
```

Comment: This (the first) will work fine if the DOM node referenced by `this.loader` is hidden. Please post some more code and/or provide a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: You need to give more information about your problem, or it will simply get closed again.

Comment: but if I reverse the animation from opacity:1 to transparent it works?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery is just altering the `opacity` while the `filter` is still staying active, making the div never actually appear for you.

My suggestion is to scrap the `style.opacity` and `style.filter`, and just set

```
style.display = 'none';
```